# Pandas change row to column and extract. Tried pivot but see Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below df:

| name | values | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| page_fans | {'value': 111, 'end_time': '2021-09-13T07:00:00+0000'} | 247111 |
| page_fans | {'value': 233, 'end_time': '2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000'} | 247111 |
| page_fans | {'value': 551, 'end_time': '2021-09-15T07:00:00+0000'} | 247111 |

but I'm trying to do this:

| page_fans | end_time | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | '2021-09-13T07:00:00+0000'} | 247111 |
| 233 | '2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000'} | 247111 |
| 551 | '2021-09-15T07:00:00+0000'} | 247111 |

The below is what I've done so far to create / clean up the df:

```
row =  {'name': 'page_fans', 'period': 'day', 'values': [{'value': 111, 'end_time': '2021-09-13T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 233, 'end_time': '2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000'}, {'value': 551, 'end_time': '2021-09-15T07:00:00+0000'}], 'title': 'Lifetime Total Likes', 'description': 'Lifetime: The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)', 'id': '247111/insights/page_fans/day'}

pat_id = r'(\d+)'
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(row)
f['id'] = (df['id'].astype(str).str.extract(pat_id))
df = df.explode('values')
```

I've tried to use df.transpose() and

`pivoted = df.pivot(columns='name').reset_index()` but I see the error:

> Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert all dict as a DataFrame with `pd.Series` (O_o):

```
out = df['values'].apply(pd.Series) \
                  .join(df['id']) \
                  .rename(columns={'value': 'page_fans'})
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   page_fans                  end_time      id
0        111  2021-09-13T07:00:00+0000  247111
1        233  2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000  247111
2        551  2021-09-15T07:00:00+0000  247111
```

With your other sample, try the code below and select what you want to keep from your original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(row)
df['id'] = df['id'].str.extract(r'^(\d+)')
```

Output:

```
>>> df['values'].apply(pd.Series).join(df)

   value                  end_time       name  ...                 title                                        description      id
0    111  2021-09-13T07:00:00+0000  page_fans  ...  Lifetime Total Likes  Lifetime: The total number of people who have ...  247111
1    233  2021-09-14T07:00:00+0000  page_fans  ...  Lifetime Total Likes  Lifetime: The total number of people who have ...  247111
2    551  2021-09-15T07:00:00+0000  page_fans  ...  Lifetime Total Likes  Lifetime: The total number of people who have ...  247111

[3 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: hi @Corralien, thanks for responding so thoroughly! when I try the 'out' var I see my rows have been duplicated. Is there a way to prevent this? Otherwise it looks great!

Comment: I hadn't noticed your index (only 0s). I slightly changed the way to create your dataframe and the duplicates are now removed. I hope it what you expect.

Comment: sorry I still see the duplication when I try the 'out' var, what could be the reason?

Comment: The way you have to build your dataframe. Try before the line `out = ...`, `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`, it should be solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Corralien! I didn't realize I forgot to add that, thanks again :)